# XML complexType with arbitrary simpleType base

Tags: xml, xsd, vtk

we are trying to save particle data in an XML format. The existing XSD code handed to me is of the form below and works more or less. However, we get problems when we try to store large unsigned long values in "DataArray_t", which seems to be due to the type (xsd:decimal) of the base of "DataArrayList_t". Since "DataArray_t" is supposed to be used for storing data of arbitrary type (int, unsigned long, but also double), I wonder if it is possible to somehow arbitrarily change the itemType of "DataArrayList_t", e.g. as an parameter given to "DataArray_t"?

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">


 <xsd:simpleType name='DataArrayList_t'>
    <xsd:list itemType='xsd:decimal'/>
  </xsd:simpleType>


  <xsd:complexType name="DataArray_t">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
      <xsd:extension base="DataArrayList_t"> <!-- hier typ der daten in liste  --> 
        <xsd:attribute name="type" use="required">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
              <xsd:enumeration value="Int8"/>
              <xsd:enumeration value="UInt8"/>
              <xsd:enumeration value="Int16"/>
              <xsd:enumeration value="UInt16"/>
              <xsd:enumeration value="Int32"/>
              <xsd:enumeration value="UInt32"/>
              <xsd:enumeration value="Int64"/>
              <xsd:enumeration value="UInt64"/>
              <xsd:enumeration value="Float32"/>
              <xsd:enumeration value="Float64"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:attribute>
        <xsd:attribute name="Name" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="NumberOfComponents" type="xsd:integer" use="required"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="format" type="xsd:string" fixed="ascii"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="offset" type="xsd:integer" use="optional"/>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
  </xsd:complexType>


  <xsd:complexType name="PieceUnstructuredGrid_t">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="PointData">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="DataArray" type="DataArray_t" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="CellData">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="DataArray" type="DataArray_t" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="Points">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="DataArray" type="DataArray_t" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="Cells">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="DataArray" type="DataArray_t" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="NumberOfPoints" type="xsd:integer" use="required"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="NumberOfCells" type="xsd:integer" use="required"/>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: Does your schema processor impose limits on the range of an xsd:decimal? I can see that being a problem for storing xsd:double values, but not large unsigned long, since integer is a subtype of decimal. However, you could consider making the item type of the list be union(xsd:decimal, xsd:double, xsd:float).

Comment: Hello @MichaelKay Sorry, I don't know the answer to your question. The schema processor is [link](https://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/). The current problem we face is that a number like 9223372036854775810 is written to file as 9223372036854775808. By stepping through the the code with gdb I found that giving the first number to such an DataArray_t will ultimately cause it to be stored in a std::vector<double>

Comment: I don't know the processor you're using but it looks as if it's limited to 64-bit integers. No easy workaround to that one.